# Convert View And Multiple Types BaseAdapter

Tags: android

I have created an adapter that feeds a list view. It is working ok but is a little jenky so I am trying to use the Convert View to avoid inflating a view on every getView call. I changed the getview method to the following

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Suggestion suggestion = getItem(position);
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView titleTv;
    ImageView checkBox;
    switch (type) {
        case Suggestion.CONTACT_SUGGESTION_ID:
            ContactSuggestion contactSuggestion = (ContactSuggestion) suggestion;
            String id = contactSuggestion.getId();
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_history_item, parent, false);
            }
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            PhotoRetreiver photoRetreiver = (PhotoRetreiver) imageView.getTag();
            if (photoRetreiver != null) {
                photoRetreiver.cancel(true);
            }
            if (images.containsKey(id)) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(id));
            } else {
                photoRetreiver = new PhotoRetreiver(context, id, imageView);
                imageView.setTag(photoRetreiver);
                photoRetreiver.execute();
            }
            titleTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
            titleTv.setText(suggestion.getTitle());
            checkBox = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favouriteIv);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
            checkBox.setId(position);
            if (suggestion.isFavourite()) {
                checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_fav_active);
                checkBox.setTag(true);
            } else {
                checkBox.setTag(false);
            }
            break;
        case Suggestion.GOOGLE_SUGGESTION_ID:
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.google_history_item, parent, false);
            }
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            titleTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
            imageView.setImageResource(resources.getIdentifier(suggestion.getInActiveImageResource(), "drawable", "com.allryder.android"));
            titleTv.setText(suggestion.getTitle());
            checkBox = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favouriteIv);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
            checkBox.setId(position);
            if (suggestion.isFavourite()) {
                checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_fav_active);
                checkBox.setTag(true);
            } else {
                checkBox.setTag(false);
            }
            break;
        case Suggestion.STATION_SUGGESTION_ID:
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.station_history_item, parent, false);
            }
            StationSuggestion stationSuggestion = (StationSuggestion) suggestion;
            StationView stationView = (StationView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stationView);
            stationView.setStationTypes(stationSuggestion.getStationTypes());
            titleTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
            titleTv.setText(suggestion.getTitle());
            checkBox = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favouriteIv);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
            checkBox.setId(position);
            if (suggestion.isFavourite()) {
                checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_fav_active);
                checkBox.setTag(true);
            } else {
                checkBox.setTag(false);
            }
            break;
        case Suggestion.CURRENT_LOCATION_SUGGESTION_ID:
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.current_location_item, parent, false);
            }
            titleTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
            titleTv.setText(suggestion.getTitle());
            break;
    }
    TextView detailTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detailTv);
    detailTv.setText(suggestion.getDescription());
    convertView.setTag(type);
    return convertView;
}
```

Then overwrote the following to methods so the adapter knows which view type is should pass into the getview method

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return getItem(position).getTypeId();
}
```

However I receive a a null pointer on this line

```
     checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
```

So checkbox is not instantiated.

You can see that I added a tag to the convert view this was just to check that the tag would equal the type when convert view is not null. And it always is.

Why the hell can the adapter not find checkbox?

Comment: checkbox is null do all the layouts have the checkbox?

Comment: nope, R.layout.current_location_item, doesn't have a checkbox

Comment: ok the other layouts have checkbox with same ids?

Comment: Yes the other 3 have a checkbox with the same id, (It's actually an imageview named check box, a bad name I know)

Comment: looks like the initialization fails. Now check which one is it. Based on the logact. there will be caused by part whihc indicates the line. Then check the correspoding xml for the id

Comment: Unfortunately it can and does fail on any of the 3 initializations